# How to translate a simple web framework in Javalin into Clojure?

Tags: java, clojure, javalin

There is a simple web framework in Javalin

```
import io.javalin.Javalin;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var app = Javalin.create(/*config*/)
            .get("/", ctx -> ctx.result("Hello World"))
            .start(7070);
    }
}
```

## Translated into Clojure.

```
(ns javalin.javalin101)

(import 'io.javalin.Javalin)

(defn -main []
  (let [app (Javalin/create)]
    (Javalin/get app "/" (fn [ctx] (.result ctx "Hello World")))
    (.start app 7070)))
```

## deps.edn

```
{:paths ["src"]
 :deps
 {org.clojure/clojure {:mvn/version "1.11.1"}
  org.clojure/core.async {:mvn/version "1.6.673"}
  org.clojure/data.json {:mvn/version "2.4.0"}
  clj-time/clj-time {:mvn/version "0.15.2"}
  ;; java 
  io.javalin/javalin {:mvn/version "5.5.0"}}}
```

When I execute with calve-repl, an error encounter

```
; Syntax error (IllegalArgumentException) compiling . at (src/javalin/javalin101.clj:7:5).
; No matching method get found taking 3 args for class io.javalin.Javalin
```

Please feel free to comment how to fix it.

Comment: have you read the error message? In the original call you only pass two parameters, in the attempt that doesn't work, you pass 3

Comment: @Stultuske, thank for you reply. I read the error messages, I am not familiar with Clojure, this is why I seek comment how to fix it

Comment: `Javalin/get` looks like a call to a *static* method. Did you try `(.get app "/" (fn [ctx] (.result ctx "Hello World")))` instead? You could possibly chain the ops: `(-> (Javalin/create) (.get "/" (fn [ctx] (.result ctx "Hello World"))) (.start 7070))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first issue with your code, is that you are making a call to a non-existent static method of the Javalin class. Your call to `get` approximately translates to:

```java
Javalin.get(app, "/", (ctx) -> ctx.result("Hello World"));
```

Just as you call `result` on `ctx` with `(.result ctx "Hello World")`, you need to call `get` the same way: `(.get app "/" (fn ...))`.

However, you will see that you are not getting the appropriate type for the handler function. Use [`reify`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reify) to create an instance of [Handler](https://javadoc.io/static/io.javalin/javalin/3.0.0/io/javalin/http/Handler.html) - you just have to add another argument to `handle` ("this"):

```
Dependency: [io.javalin/javalin "5.5.0"]

(ns ...
  (:import (io.javalin Javalin)
           (io.javalin.http Handler))
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main []
  (doto (Javalin/create)
    (.get "/" (reify Handler
                (handle [_ ctx] (.result ctx "Hello World"))))
    (.start 7070)))
```

You can also use [`proxy`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/proxy):

```
(defn -main []
  (doto (Javalin/create)
    (.get "/" (proxy [Handler] []
                (handle [ctx] (.result ctx "Hello World"))))
    (.start 7070)))
```

Comment: `Handler` is an interface. Use `reify` for interfaces, and `proxy` only in dire need. Your way works, of course, but `reify` has been better since 2010.

Comment: amalloy, martin thank you for your comment, Clojure web services; this is a whole new concept to me. I am reading "https://practical.li/clojure-web-services/" to figure out what it is. thank you for your help.